# function and the Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis

is if function $f$ is Lipschitz function

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le M |x-y|$$

then $f$ is automatically bounded?

why?

Comment: It is not. That depends on your domain. For example any linear function $y = ax+b$ is Lipschitz and is not bound if the domain is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The line $y = x$ is Lipschitz with constant $1$.

---

If a function is Lipschitz on a *compact* set $K$, then it's bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "automatically bounded" in the sense that there exists $B > 0$ such that $\vert f(y) \vert \le B$ for all $y$, as the Lipschitz continuous function $f(x) = x$ illustrates; it is however *finite* for all *finite* $y$ since $\vert \vert f(x) \vert - \vert f(y) \vert \vert \le \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \le M \vert x - y \vert$, whence, if we choose a fixed $x_0$, we obtain  $\vert \vert f(x_0) \vert - \vert f(y) \vert \vert \le M \vert x_0 - y \vert$, which shows that $\vert f(y) \vert < \infty$ for $\vert y \vert < \infty$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***